I want to minus 2 columns of 2 different pandas using where condition
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'NAME' : ['A','B','L','M','Q'],'PRICE' : [10,20,30,40,50]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'NAME' : ['A','L','Q','M','B'],'PRICE' : [60,80,70,70,60]})

I want to subtract df1 price  from df2 price based on the condition where name from df1 == name from df2
Expected Answer :
NAME : 'A'    'B'   'L'   'M'    'Q'
               Price: 50   40  50  30  20

Is there any way to do this ?

Merge the two dataframes on NAME and then subtract:
tmp = df2.merge(df1, on="NAME", how="left")
tmp["PRICE"] = tmp["PRICE_x"] - tmp["PRICE_y"]

tmp = tmp[["NAME", "PRICE"]].merge(df2, on="NAME", how="right")
df2["PRICE"] = tmp["PRICE_x"]

print(df2)

Prints:
  NAME  PRICE
0    A     50
1    L     50
2    Q     20
3    M     30
4    B     40


I think it's risky to reassign to the input after a merge. merge doesn't conserve the index, and even if a range index is used it might reorder the rows ;)

I could use this. it is working fine. thank you so much. i am not doing the last part. just subtracting price_x and price_y is giving me correct answer. thank you

@mona I don't want to be picky, but this solution is actually incorrect. If you reverse df2 then A/B/M will be assigned incorrect values. To test: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'NAME' : ['A','L','Q','M','B'],'PRICE' : [60,80,70,70,60]})[::-1]. You cannot re-assign the output of a merge to the original inputs without risks since the index was lost.

You can use a common index with set_index:
out = (df2.set_index('NAME')
          .sub(df1.set_index('NAME'))
          .reset_index()
      )

NB. you shouldn't have duplicated names in more than one of the inputs.
If you can't set the index or have duplicates in df1, you could use map:
df1['PRICE'] = (df1['NAME'].map(df2.set_index('NAME')['PRICE'])
                -df1['PRICE']
               )

Output:
  NAME  PRICE
0    A     50
1    B     40
2    L     50
3    M     30
4    Q     20


I am sorry I made a mistake here. I cant set is as index as df2 has multiple rows with same name. Let me modify my question

@mona Having duplicates in one of the dataframes shouldn't be an issue. But you can always map from df2 (see update)

@mona you never updated the question

Hello sorry but I got the answer. I also marked the correct answer.

thanks for your help though. I learned something new.

@mona except this answer is incorrect, but up to you to use it
